# Redirect always to index.php

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm trying to relocate a site into a temporary folder in order to install a CMS in the root. The redirect works but all the internal links in the site now take me back to the index page in the temporary folder. The .htaccess in the root is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/old/ [R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

it's because you're redirecting everything to the new url. You should put something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/old [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/old/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

PS: The $1 take the arguments in expression

PS2: You should not use code 301 for a temporary redirect, the 302 is more appropriate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this. Didn't know about $1.